# INSERT INTO SELECT FROM doesnt work. Not even an error

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert

```
INSERT INTO kid_progress_Backup (userid)
SELECT id
FROM users1
WHERE id>770
```

I am a newbie but I copied and pasted then tried on my sqlite tables. 
id is the autoincrement so maybe there is a problem there. I also tried changing id and using another column but that doesnt work either.
An error didnt even pop up- which is really weird.

Basically I have two tables. I have added records to the first and now I want to add that nuber of records to the other table. The relationship of keys is users1.id to kid_progress_Backup.userid. Then I need to add/chabge values in the kid_progress_Backup table according to some values in the users1 table. First I am just trying to add the same amount of new records than I was going to do a UPDATE and SET.

Comment: and `select id from users1 where id>770` gives you results ?

Comment: And _how_ do you know it didn't work? Does `SELECT id FROM users1 WHERE id > 770` give you any results? Are you in the same session or ahve you committed when checking the inserted records? Are there any triggers on `kid_progress_Backup`?

Comment: YES, it gives me back the new rows - well the id numbers from 770 onwards so I would expect to see those in the usersid column but they dont appear a the end of the table.

Comment: Is this how I answer ie: via a comment of do I press ANSWER YOUR QUESTION

Comment: What do you mean with "don't appear at the *end of the table*" - there is no such thing as "the end of a table" in a relational database.

Comment: At the end of the db means the last recordset as presented in the table I use sqlite firefox plugin. I am in the same session and I have tried coming out and back in. No triggers. The last sql mentioned comes up with an error and I prefer something simple. My sql should work in theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be occurred, because there are **some other fields** in **kid_progress_Backup**, **which can't be NULL and does not have default values**.

If you use SQLite, then you should use INSERT OR REPLACE statement for your case. So, you will not need an UPDATE. But you should define PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE INDEX on userid column.

Comment: Excellent answer as the sql was correct. I checked the db and you're right. BUT how do I add the other columns then. There is only one column that is shared but how do I add coins, level columns?

Comment: May be you have to change logic. Can you share more details of your DB and data, that you need to put in **kid_progress_Backup**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL Query

```
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT kid_progress_Backup ON

    INSERT INTO kid_progress_Backup (userid)
    SELECT id
    FROM users1
    WHERE id>770

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT kid_progress_Backup OFF
```

Answer (score -1):

try somethinglike this:

INSERT INTO kid_progress_Backup(userid) VALUES(SELECT id FROM users1 WHERE id>770);